# How to marshal a slice of struct to valid JSON

Tags: go

I'm writing a Golang api and client but can't get valid json from a slice of structs in the api. The result I get in my client looks like this.

> [{0 Mark 1234 false} {0 John 3456 false}]

I need this json to look like

> [{"id":0, "name":Mark, "pin":1234, "active":false} {"id":0, "name":John, "pin":3456, "active":false}]

I can't find examples showing me how to code this properly and this is not a duplicate of anything I can find despite a warning that it is. While my client successfully parses the JSON back to a struct, I ***also*** need it to return JSON to an IOS client which is requesting it. The flow is API -> API -> iOS client. I don't know how to produce JSON from the struct for the iOS client.

Here is my api code.

```
// Employee model
type Employee struct {
    EmployeeID int64  `json:"id"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Pin        int    `json:"pin"`
    Active     bool   `json:"active"`
}

func getEmployees(db *sql.DB, venueID int64) ([]Employee, error) {

    var employee Employee

    var employees []Employee

    query, err := db.Query("SELECT id, name, pin FROM employees WHERE active=1 AND venue_id=? ORDER BY name", venueID)
    if err != nil {
        return employees, err
    }

    defer query.Close()

    for query.Next() {
        err = query.Scan(&employee.EmployeeID, &employee.Name, &employee.Pin)
        if err != nil {
            return employees, err
        }
        employees = append(employees, employee)
    }

    return employees, err
}



func (rs *appResource) listEmployees(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var venue Venue

    token := getToken(r)

    fmt.Println(token)

    venue, err := getVenue(rs.db, token)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    venueID := venue.VenueID

    if !(venueID > 0) {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    employees, err := getEmployees(rs.db, venueID)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(employees[0].EmployeeID)

    employeesJSON, err := json.Marshal(employees)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    w.Write([]byte(employeesJSON))

}
```

Here is my client code:

```
func (rs *appResource) getEmployees(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    path := rs.url + "/employees"

    fmt.Println(path)

    res, err := rs.client.Get(path)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error in get")
        log.Fatal(err)
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()

    if res.StatusCode == 500 {
        fmt.Printf("res.StatusCode: %d\n", res.StatusCode)
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusInternalServerError), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return

    }

    if res.StatusCode == 404 {
        fmt.Printf("res.StatusCode: %d\n", res.StatusCode)
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusInternalServerError), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

// here I want to return actual JSON to an iOS client    

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("{ok}"))
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190154/discussion-on-question-by-markhorrocks-how-to-marshal-a-slice-of-struct-to-valid).

Comment: I need both, I would return JSON to the requesting client if I knew how, that's why there is no code to do produce JSON.

Comment: Can you continue the discussion in chat? Extended comments trip auto flags and now I'm being pinged.

Comment: No, I'm not, I'm returning a status and {ok}, I want to return the contents of my struct as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is currently printing is the content of a struct, not JSON. When you print the contents of a struct, by default, you will print just the values within that struct. That means that `fmt.Println(employees.EmployeeList)` will produce something like:

```
[{0 Mark 1234 false} {0 John 3456 false}]
```

If you want to also print field values, you'll need to add a format 'verb' `%+v` which will print field names. `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", employees.EmployeeList)` should print something like:

```
[{id:0 name:Mark pin:1234 active:false} {id:0 name:John pin:3456 active:false}]
```

I think what you actually want to look at doing is marshalling your data back into a JSON string again in order to write that content back out for the client.

Comment: Almost there but there is no comma separation.

Comment: Where is it fixed? I actually want the commas :) Your print string isn't giving me any.

Comment: I fixed the expected output in my answer. The line that you're printing isn't JSON but a struct. If you want to output JSON, you'll have to convert this struct to a JSON string.

Comment: How can I convert this to a valid JSON string?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually surprised that your code is running at all since you have 2 unused variables (err,err at listEmployees).
any way that should work, added an fmt.Println so you will be able to see the result at the console

```
 type Employee struct {
        ID     int    `json:"id"`
        Name   string `json:"name"`
        Pin    int    `json:"pin"`
        Active bool   `json:"active"`
    }

    func (rs *appResource) listEmployees(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        employees, _:= getEmployees(rs.db)
        employeesJSON, _:= json.Marshal(employees)
        fmt.Ptintln(string(employeesJSON))
        w.Write(employeesJSON)
    }
```

another run example:

```
func main() {
    emp := Employee{
        ID:     1,
        Name:   "Mark",
        Pin:    1234,
        Active: true,
    }
    if jsn, err := json.Marshal(emp); err == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(jsn))
    } else {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

}

type Employee struct {
    ID     int    `json:"id"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Pin    int    `json:"pin"`
    Active bool   `json:"active"`
}
```

Output:

> {"id":1,"name":"Mark","pin":1234,"active":true}

Comment: The reason I have unused error vars is simply that I removed the error checking for brevity in this question. I have seen many examples of hard coded struct data marshaling to json but this doesn't work with my code where the data is dynamically loaded in a sql query.

Comment: @markhorrocks it's shouldn't matter if  the data loaded from an sql query or been hard coded, at the end you have a slice of Employee that getting marshaled. may you please edit your post and add a debug picture with the slice data? 
just before marshaling it

Comment: It was correct but the answer by @antham is correct if I can get comma separation.

Comment: I don't get output like that, I wish it did. My code gives me output like this. `[{EmployeeID:3 Name:Mark Pin:1234 Active:false} {EmployeeID:4 Name:John Pin:3456 Active:false}]`

Comment: Worked for me thanks! Just watch out for the typo Ptintln in the listEmployees function - just flip it to Println and all is good : )

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want is a dump of the json, here you dump the struct, what you could do with the struct is to dump key and value with %+v in a Printf, have a look here : https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing.

Comment: While your suggestion does give me the keys it does not give me comma separation.